# -webkit-background-clip:text; is not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a simple loading page. I have added an animation for a wave effect and its working fine but as I clip the background to the text, the background disappears...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #262626;
  font-family: ariel;
}

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-image: url(back.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: left 0 top 50px;
  }
  20% {
    background-position: left 800px top -50px;
  }
  40% {
    background-position: left 1800px top -60px;
  }
  60% {
    background-position: left 2400px top -80px;
  }
  80% {
    background-position: left 3400px top -50px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: left 4400px top 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You will need to apply `color: transparent` in `h1` to `background-clip: text` work

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #262626;
  font-family: ariel;
}

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 6em;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: left 0 top 50px;
  }
  20% {
    background-position: left 800px top -50px;
  }
  40% {
    background-position: left 1800px top -60px;
  }
  60% {
    background-position: left 2400px top -80px;
  }
  80% {
    background-position: left 3400px top -50px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: left 4400px top 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
```